# Prove $l^2$ norm obeys the triangle inequality

Tags: proof-verification, normed-spaces, inner-products, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I'm trying to work through Exercise 3 from [this blog post](http://sadeepj.blogspot.com/2013/09/a-tutorial-introduction-to-reproducing.html), which is essentially a proof of the validity of the $l^2$ norm:

> Exercise 3: Let $(\mathcal{V},\left<\cdot,\cdot\right>)$ be an inner product space. Show, that $||x|| = \sqrt{\left<x,x\right>}\ \forall x \in \mathcal{V}$ is a normed vector space.

So far my working is as follows (I apologise for the hand-written working, I can convert it to MathJax if required by the site standards);

[image: Hand working out]

Which is where I get stuck. Can anyone advise how to finish showing the triangle inequality holds for the $l^2$ norm? I think I may need to use the Schwartz inequality, but I'm not sure how to apply it in the context.

Comment: Note that the LHS in your last step is $$ \langle x,y \rangle + \langle y,x \rangle = \langle x,y \rangle + \overline{\langle x,y \rangle} = 2 \Re \langle x,y \rangle, $$ and conclude using the Schwartz inequality. (Recall also that $\Re z \leq |z|$ for any complex number.)

Comment: Aha! I was closer than I realised! Thanks @MisterRiemann!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any inner product satisfies the C-S inequality $ |\langle x, y \rangle| \leq \|x\| \|y\|$ from which you can complete your argument immediately.